# Application.Run Attempted to read or write protected memory

Tags: c#, winforms, emgucv

[image: DETAILS on STACK TRACE]

Briefly, my application is a windows form that has picturebox to show live feed from camera that detects phone screen using ROI (Region of interest).

Below is the exception

```
 -$exception {System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
 at System.Drawing.SafeNativeMethods.Gdip.GdipDrawImageRectI(HandleRef graphics, HandleRef image, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 width, Int32 height)
 at System.Drawing.Graphics.DrawImage(Image image, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 width, Int32 height)
 at System.Drawing.Graphics.DrawImage(Image image, Rectangle rect)
 at System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox.OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
 at System.Windows.Forms.Control.PaintWithErrorHandling(PaintEventArgs e, Int16 layer)
 at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmPaint(Message& m)
 at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
 at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)} System.AccessViolationException
```

Below is the Stack Trace

```
    StackTrace  "at System.Drawing.SafeNativeMethods.Gdip.GdipDrawImageRectI(HandleRef graphics, HandleRef image, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 width, Int32 height)\r\n   at System.Drawing.Graphics.DrawImage(Image image, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 width, Int32 height)\r\n   
    at System.Drawing.Graphics.DrawImage(Image image, Rectangle rect)\r\n   at System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox.OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)\r\n   
    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.PaintWithErrorHandling(PaintEventArgs e, Int16 layer)\r\n   
    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmPaint(Message& m)\r\n   
    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)\r\n    
    at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)"  string
```

Attempted to write or read protected memory will occur if I leave my application run at the following line, **Application.Run(MMI.MainMDI);** like below

```
   static void Init()
    {
        MMI.Data = new CommonDataType();

        MMI.MainMDI = new MDIMain();
        MMI.MainMDI.Show();

        MMI.FrmMain = new FormMain();

        MMI.MainMDI.Text = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name;

        MMI.FrmMain.MdiParent = MMI.MainMDI;
        
        MMI.FrmMain.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
        MMI.FrmMain.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(MMI.MainMDI.ClientRectangle.Location.X, MMI.MainMDI.ClientRectangle.Y);
        MMI.FrmMain.Width = MMI.MainMDI.ClientRectangle.Size.Width - 10;

        MMI.FrmMain.Show();
       
        GenericMachine.SetMessageLogForm(MMI.FrmMsg);

        if (!MMI.Data.Config.LoadConfig())
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error Loading Config File Data... Application Will Be Closed");
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }

        MMI.DBCtrl = new MainDBControl();
        MMI.DBCtrl.Start();

        MMI.DevCtrl = new MainDevControl();
        MMI.DevCtrl.Start();

        MMI.IOCtrl = new MainIOControl();
        MMI.IOCtrl.Start();

        MMI.CycleCtrl = new MainCycleControl();
        MMI.CycleCtrl.Start();
    }

    static void DeInit()
    {
        if (MMI.IOCtrl != null) MMI.IOCtrl.Dispose();
        if (MMI.DevCtrl != null) MMI.DevCtrl.Dispose();
        if (MMI.DBCtrl != null) MMI.DBCtrl.Dispose();
        if (MMI.CycleCtrl != null) MMI.CycleCtrl.Dispose();
        EndTask("loadmultipleimages.exe");
        EndTask("EXCEL.EXE");
    }

   static System.Threading.Mutex mutex = new System.Threading.Mutex(true, "Sensata MMI Application");

    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        if (mutex.WaitOne(TimeSpan.Zero, true))
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Init();
            Application.Run(MMI.MainMDI);
            DeInit();
            mutex.ReleaseMutex();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Application Already Running - Only One Instance is Allowed at One Time");
        }
    }
```

When I checked the Stack Trace, the source was coming from System.Drawing which I suspected coming from my FORM class.  I think it is because the picturebox keeps running even when there is no phone screen is detected. So, basically my formshown method will always refresh and trigger event handler refreshscreen1 method, since bool m_camerachoosen is always true to ensure the camera is always on display on picturebox.Image, it will keep looping into the **DetectText function**. Is there a way to solve this **Attempted to read or write protected memory**? I have been facing this issue for almost 1 month plus.

```
    private void FormMain_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (m_screenRefreshTimer1 == null)
        {
            m_screenRefreshTimer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
            m_screenRefreshTimer1.Interval = 200;
            m_screenRefreshTimer1.Tick += new System.EventHandler(refreshScreen1);
            m_screenRefreshTimer1.Start();
        }

        if (m_screenRefreshTimer2 == null)
        {
            m_screenRefreshTimer2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
            m_screenRefreshTimer2.Interval = 1000;
            m_screenRefreshTimer2.Tick += new System.EventHandler(refreshScreen2);
            m_screenRefreshTimer2.Start();
        }
    }

    private void refreshScreen1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (MMI.CycleCtrl == null) return;

        m_screenRefreshTimer1.Stop();
        txtBoxRisk.Text = "";
        txtBoxDateTime.Text = "";
        txtBoxMYS.Text = "";
        txtboxhint.Text = MMI.Data.Mach.Hint;
        txtboxMSG.Text = MMI.Data.Mach.DBMessage;

        if (m_Camerachosen)
        {
            txtboxhint.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Aqua;
            //md.Hint = "PLEASE PLACE YOUR PHONE AT THE DESIGNATED AREA";
            DetectText(myImage);
        }
    }

   private void refreshScreen2(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      m_screenRefreshTimer2.Stop();
      m_screenRefreshTimer2.Start();
   }

    private void startToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        VideoCaptureDevice = new VideoCaptureDevice(filterInfoCollection[comboBox1.SelectedIndex].MonikerString);
        VideoCaptureDevice.NewFrame += VideoCaptureDevice_NewFrame;
        VideoCaptureDevice.Start();
    }

    private void VideoCaptureDevice_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        Bitmap picboxclone = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
        myImage = new Image<Bgr, Byte>(picboxclone);
        m_Camerachosen = true;
    }

    private void DetectText(Image<Bgr, byte> img)
    {
        Image<Bgr, byte> imgclone = img;
        Image<Gray, byte> sobel = img.Convert<Gray, byte>().Sobel(1, 0, 3).AbsDiff(new Gray(0.0)).Convert<Gray, byte>().ThresholdBinary(new Gray(90), new Gray(255));
        var mask = img.Convert<Gray, byte>().SmoothMedian(3).
                    ThresholdBinary(new Gray(150), new Gray(255));

        Mat SE = CvInvoke.GetStructuringElement(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.ElementShape.Rectangle, new Size(1, 1), new Point(-1, -1));
        sobel = sobel.MorphologyEx(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.MorphOp.Dilate, SE, new Point(-1, -1), 1, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.BorderType.Reflect, new MCvScalar(255));


        Emgu.CV.Util.VectorOfVectorOfPoint contours = new Emgu.CV.Util.VectorOfVectorOfPoint();
        Emgu.CV.Util.VectorOfVectorOfPoint contours2 = new Emgu.CV.Util.VectorOfVectorOfPoint();

        Mat m = new Mat();

        CvInvoke.FindContours(sobel, contours, m, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.RetrType.External, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.ChainApproxMethod.ChainApproxSimple);
        CvInvoke.FindContours(mask, contours2, m, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.RetrType.External, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.ChainApproxMethod.ChainApproxSimple);

        List<Rectangle> list = new List<Rectangle>();
        Rectangle maskrect = new Rectangle();
   }
```

Comment: I would suggest to edit your question, put the complete stacktrace of the exception in it, add probably relevant tag `emgucv` and remove irrelevant ones like `windows-forms-designer` and `picturebox`.

Comment: It's not much better... Copy the *`StackTrace`* or all the details of your exception *as text* and insert it as text. The stacktrace is still not visible.

Comment: Alright, gotcha. Added both stacktrace and exception details

Comment: What is `Init()`? Why do you have a Timer that is started when the Form is shown and tries to pass an Image that is not generated until you start the video capture using a `MenuItem`? - This Timer appears to useless, since it's stopped at its first iteration. Just remove it. The other Timer is not clear what is doing, you haven't posted the code in its handler. Are you restarting the first Timer there?

Comment: The timer is to ensure that Windows Form is always displayed with the latest info. The other timer is just empty handler with stop & start timer. So basically the first timer is the main timer.

Comment: I have added Init() & second timer method for your reference

Comment: Sometimes `Bitmap` related errors can be caused because the size of the `Bitmap` is `(0, 0)`.